# Cordova iOS keyboard on input or textarea scroll to correct place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

So I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard) to prevent the whole webview from scrolling to the correct place on keyboard show when clicking on an `<input>` or `<textarea>` by doing:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
```

This works well, but I would like to be able to move it to the right spot manually, within the page using javascript/css. I assume it's a combination of using `offset().top`, while also adding more padding if the page height is too "short" and goes under the keyboard.